# QComboBox not rendering added items correctly

Tags: c++, qt5

I have strange behavior with `QComboBox`, basically I listen on currentIndexChanged signal, then based on that index a second `QComboBox` get filled from `QStrList`. My problem is the second `QComboBox` gets filled normally but not showing the text correctly until I click on item then it shows up, I use a slot to fill up the `QComboBox`.

```
InfoEmployer::InfoEmployer(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::InfoEmployer)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->gradeCombo->addItem("");
    ui->gradeCombo->addItem("200");
    ui->gradeCombo->addItem("300");
    ui->gradeCombo->addItem("400");
    ui->gradeCombo->addItem("500");
    ui->gradeCombo->addItem("600");
    ui->gradeCombo->addItem("700");

    QStringList levels;
    levels << "10" << "20" << "30" << "40" << "50" << "60" << "70" << "80" << "90" << "100" << "110" << "120";
    m_levelsContainer[0] = levels;
    levels.clear();
    levels << "11" << "22" << "33" << "44" << "55" << "66" << "77" << "88" << "99" << "110" << "120" << "131";
    m_levelsContainer[1] = levels;
    levels.clear();
    levels << "12" << "24" << "36" << "48" << "60" << "72" << "84" << "96" << "108" << "120" << "132" << "144";
    m_levelsContainer[2] = levels;
    levels.clear();
    levels << "13" << "26" << "39" << "53" << "66" << "79" << "92" << "105" << "118" << "132" << "145" << "158";
    m_levelsContainer[3] = levels;
    levels.clear();
    levels << "14" << "29" << "43" << "58" << "72" << "86" << "101" << "115" << "130" << "144" << "158" << "173";
    m_levelsContainer[4] = levels;
    levels.clear();
    levels << "16" << "32" << "47" << "63" << "79" << "95" << "110" << "126" << "142" << "158" << "173" << "189";
    m_levelsContainer[5] = levels;
    levels.clear();

    connect(ui->gradeCombo, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(getGradeLevels(int)));
}

// The slot
    void InfoEmployer::getGradeLevels(int indx)
    {
        if(indx != 0)
        {
            ui->levelCombo->clear();
            QStringList levels = m_levelsContainer[indx - 1];
            for(int i = 0; i < levels.length(); ++i)
                ui->levelCombo->addItem(levels[i]);
        }
    }
```

Note this problem is only happen to me when I fill `QComboBox` programmatically.

**UPDATE**

I found that the problem is not in my code, but it is on `QComboBox`! Inserting more then 10 items on `QComboBox` make it not showing items correctly, if I insert less then or ten items all items shows up correctly. 
My Qt verions is 5.0.2 with MinGW 4.7, please test and confirm that.

Comment: user2644295, I see no problems in your code. Please, would you explain again what your problem is? If what you mean with _"...not showing the text correctly until I click on item then it shows up..."_ is that on start up your second `QComboBox` doesn't contain any value, it is because you're not initializing it. It fills for the first time, just the first time the `currentIndexChanged(int)` signal of the `ui->gradeCombo` is emitted.

Comment: @mhcuervo When my app start up, I chose a value from gradeCombo witch is the first `QComboBox`, based on that value I fill the the second `QComboBox` (levelCombo). My problem is the text is not visible until I click on item, if I drop down the second `QComboBox` I still can see it filled up but text not visible. I hope you understand me now.

Comment: I understand now. I prepared a testing project and everything runs as it should. I'm calling `ui->gradeCombo->setCurrentIndex();` to set up a starting value to the `gradeCombo` and the values of the `levelCombo` are shown correctly. Are you calling `setCurrentIndex()` after connecting the signal `connect(ui->gradeCombo, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(getGradeLevels(int)));` ?

Comment: Yes, can it be that the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this

```
ui->levelCombo->setCurrentIndex(-1); // deselect items, i have some proplems without this line
ui->levelCombo->setCurrentIndex(0); // select first item in combobox
```

Comment: It seems like my Qt has a bug, I down grade to Qt 4.8.3 and the problem gone.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like my Qt has a bug, I down grade to Qt 4.8.3 and the problem is gone.